# How can I remember a past value in setInterval?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that continually generates two random numbers ranging from 0 to 7. These two numbers correspond to an id in my DOM.

How do I ensure that the next interval doesn't give the same two numbers in the same order as the last interval (in other words, the giving the same id as the LAST interval)?

If it is the case that they are the same, how do I skip this interval and go on to the next without it waiting for the interval time?

```
function chooserandomtile() {
    
    cycle = setInterval(() => {
        let i_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);  
        let j_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        var id = i_random + ',' + j_random;

        var target = document.getElementById(id);
        if (target.classList.contains('target') || target.contains(player)) {
        } else {
            target.classList.add('target');
        }

        console.log(id);
        console.log(document.getElementById(id));
        
    }, interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a variable that will persist outside the scope of your method, and set it to keep track of the previous value. If your random logic produces the same ID as the previous time, try again until it gives you a different value.

```
function chooserandomtile() {
    let lastId;
    cycle = setInterval(() => {
        let id;
        do {
            let i_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);  
            let j_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            id = i_random + ',' + j_random;
        } while (id === lastId)
        lastId = id;

        var target = document.getElementById(id);
        if (target.classList.contains('target') || target.contains(player)) {
        } else {
            target.classList.add('target');
        }

        console.log(id);
        console.log(document.getElementById(id));
        
    }, interval);
```

Comment: I really overthunk that. Thank you.